# Style a part of the defaultMessage in react-intl

Tags: react-intl

I need some way to style a part of the defaultMessage in react-intl, the {Text_to_be_bold} needs to be bold but the rest of the text should stay as it is. Is there any support for that in react-intl or should I manage it manually? Thanks in advance

```
import { defineMessages } from 'react-intl';

const messagePath = 'some path';

export default defineMessages({
  discountMessage: {
    defaultMessage:
      '{Text_to_be_bold} normal text',
    id: `${messagePath}.thisMessage`,
  },
});
```

I read the documentation and expect some proper solution